# mysql query - how to escape apostrophe?

Tags: query, mysql, wpdb

I've got this query:

```
$tenantsInfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM exp_ten WHERE tenant_number = " . (int) $user->ID);
```

I use some echo to show data on frontend:

```
if ($tenantsInfo) {
        foreach ($tenantsInfo as $tenant) { 
           echo "<h2>Welcome," . " " .$tenant->tenant_name. "</h2>";
```

When data, like tenant's name contains apostrophe, no data is displayed on frontend.

Could somebody please help me change mysql statement so apostrophe could be escaped? Or maybe there is different solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) when outputting a string value inside tags. Use [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) when you're outputting a string value inside an `attribute=""`. If you're outputting a URL, use [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) instead of those two.

```
if ($tenantsInfo) {
        foreach ($tenantsInfo as $tenant) { 
           echo "<h2>Welcome, " . esc_html( $tenant->tenant_name ) . "</h2>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is not clear how you get the data inside the `exp_ten` table I would suggest use the `esc_attr( $tenant->tenant_name )` which will encode the apostrophe along other things.

[More info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/)

Comment: Even better, use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: Unfortunately non of above works. Is it the correct use of $wpdb->prepare() ?: 

` $tenantsInfo =` 
`$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( `
 `"`
  `SELECT * `
  `FROM exp_ten `
  `WHERE tenant_number = %s`
 `", `
 `$user->ID`
`) );`

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What result is returned?